# How do I use a file like a memory buffer in Python?

Tags: python, file, memory, buffer, micropython

I don't know the correct terminology, maybe it's called page file, but I'm not sure. I need a way to use an on-disk file as a buffer, like `bytearray`. It should be able to do things like `a = buffer[100:200]` and `buffer[33] = 127` without the code having to be aware that it's reading from and writing to a file in the background.

Basically I need the opposite of `bytesIO`, which uses memory with a file interface. I need a way to use a file with a memory buffer interface. And ideally it doesn't write to the file everytime the data is changed (but it's ok if it does).

The reason I need this functionality is because I use packages that expect data to be in a buffer object, but I only have 4MB of memory available. It's impossible to load the files into memory. So I need an object that acts like a `bytearray` for example, but reads and writes data directly to a file, not memory.

In my use case I need a micropython module, but a standard python module might work as well. Are there any modules that would do what I need?

Comment: You might need to use some low level `file.seek`ing for that

Comment: [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html#module-mmap) ?

Comment: @jvx8ss "without the code having to be aware that it's reading from and writing to a file in the background" "The reason I need this functionality is because I use packages that expect data to be in a buffer object"

Comment: @0x0fba mmap does not exist for micropython, so it's not an option. Also it does not do what I need. It copies the full mapping into memory. It's not possible to map a 100MB file with mmap but only use 1MB of cache memory and it's an OS-specific functionality, not cpython.

Comment: @uzumaki Maybe if you make a class that internally uses `file.seek` and use `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to achieve the `buffer[100:200], buffer[33] = 127` that you want?

Comment: @jvx8ss Yes, but it would also need caching for best performance. I thought such a basic thing would already exist in python as a built-in or has already been implemented by someone else. I'm not a professional programmer, so my approach would be highly inefficient guaranteed. What about the shelve module? It seems to be pretty close to what I need, however it uses a key-value interface, but it does read/write directly to disk. If only such a module would exist with an array interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can something like this work for you?

```py
class Memfile:

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        if type(key) is int:
            self.file.seek(key)
            return self.file.read(1)
        if type(key) is slice:
            self.file.seek(key.start)
            return self.file.read(key.stop - key.start)

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        assert(type(val) == bytes or type(val) == bytearray)
        if type(key) is slice:
            assert(key.stop - key.start == len(val))
            self.file.seek(key.start)
            self.file.write(val)
        if type(key) is int:
            assert(len(val) == 1)
            self.file.seek(key)
            self.file.write(val)

    def close(self):
        self.file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mf = Memfile(open("data", "r+b")) # Assuming the file 'data' have 10+ bytes
    mf[0:10] = b'\x00'*10
    print(mf[0:10]) # b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
    mf[0:2] = b'\xff\xff'
    print(mf[0:10]) # b'\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
    print(mf[2]) # b'\x00'
    print(mf[1]) # b'\xff'
    mf[0:4] = b'\xde\xad\xbe\xef'
    print(mf[0:4]) # b'\xde\xad\xbe\xef'
    mf.close()
```

Note that if this solutions fits your needs you will need to do plenty of testing here

Comment: Yes, this would be the basic implementation of what I need. Is there a caching package that could be patched into the class? One that would read from the cache if possible and flush the cache to disk when it's full. Also shouldn't it be `self.file.read(key.stop - key.start)` ?

Comment: Your right, it should `self.file.read(key.stop - key.start)`. I don't know about the caching tough, sorry